# Get Youtube playlist by Title

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to create a private youtube playlist with the title 'my very unique title'. I'm able to create private playlists. But I'd like to create it only if it doesn't exists yet. 
So next thing I've done is getting the private playlists. 
I can retrieve the private playlists of an authorized user with the following query:

```
var q = 'my very unique title';

var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.list({
 // mine: true indicates that we want to retrieve the channel for the authenticated user.
   mine: 'true',
   part: 'snippet',
   maxResults: 10,
   //q : q //it was worth a try, no? :-) 
 });
request.execute(function(response) {
   playlistId = response.result.items[0].id;
   console.log("playlistid: "+playlistId);
 });
```

My question is: how can I query the youtube api for a playlistId with title e.g "my very unique title"? Do I have to loop the results myself? 
I've read the documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list
but haven't found anything about filtering by title.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to do a direct word search is with the "search" parameter ( info found [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search)).
But this will return for ALL of youtube and has a 100 Quota cost per search.

I would recommend to use the "playlists.list" to do your search.
Then you can look at each  one for your "title".

```
[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [kind] => youtube#playlist
                [etag] => "uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/26W6-xxxxxxxx"
                [id] => PLsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                [snippet] => Array
                    (
                        [publishedAt] => some date
                        [channelId] => channelId
                        [title] => title you are looking for
                        [description] => Some description
                        [thumbnails] => Array
```

First will be [0] node, up to node [49] if that many.
And yes you will need to loop through the results each node at a time.